# When trying to access a array of values for keys in a dictionary I keep getting "KeyError: (whatever index I try to access)

Tags: python, arrays, selenium, dictionary

I have this dictionary(with Selenium list elements with a array of string defining some of the elements attributes):

```
#The dictionary has this structure.
{0: {0: ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']}, 1: {1: ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']}}
```

And when I print the whole dictionary it has this structure and I get no errors.
But when I try to access a specific value for a key(for example string1 in the above example):

```
myPath\for\the\file\file.py, line in function
    print(myDictionary[0][0])
    KeyError: 0
```

Anyone knows why it does not work?

Comment: is it `'0'` or `0` for the key?

Comment: First rule of debugging: print the object which is giving you problems to see what the structure is. Do print(myDictionary) and see what it looks like.

Comment: @Epsi95 It is just ```0```

Comment: @ScienceSnake Just did it. Sometimes I wonder how I have acommplished the feat of being able to talk when I'm this dumb. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Java and dictionaries weren't a thing(or at least I didn't use them) so I had no idea how to use them before I used them.
This led to creating a element of the dictionary like this:

```
mydictionary[i] = {i: [some attributes]}
```

instead of:

```
mydictionary[i] = [some attributes]
```